# Doxygen and multiple #defines with the same name

Tags: c++, doxygen

This is a small experiment I tried out with Doxygen. 
Say I have 6 files:

h1.h:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int func1();
}
```

f1Data.h:

```
#define val 10
```

f1.cpp:

```
#include "h1.h"
#include "f1Data.h"

int A::func1()
{
    return val;
}
```

h2.h:

```
#include "h1.h"

class B: public A
{
    public:
        int func2();
};
```

f2Data.h

```
#define val 20
```

f2.cpp

```
#include "h2.h"
#include "f2Data.h"

int B::func2()
{
    return val;
}
```

When I put GENERATE_XML=yes and CALL_GRAPH=yes in my configuration file and run doxygen, I see a bug in the generated XML file. In particular, I see that among the references of A::func1() the #defined value from f2Data.h is given instead of the #defined value from f1Data.h. This happens only when the name of the macro is same in both the files[In this case, ***val***].

Can anyone tell me if this is a bug with doxygen or incorrect usage of doxygen on my part?

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen makes a couple of assumptions while processing the code:

1. The headers are properly guarded (so they need to be processed only once).
2. Public symbol names are unique within a single project.

These are generally good programming practices, but not enforced by C as your example demonstrates.

If you do not adhering two the above rules, the output of doxygen can be incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has my upvote, but I do not have the required reputation!